# Incrase / decrase div size with 1 px on click button

Tags: php, jquery

I've made a website with windows PVC and doors PVC products.
I want to make order page with a calculator. it's working but I need now to animate the configuration of the window.( example: http://orasvirtual.ro/images/a.JPG)
so, the default window size is 250px height and 350px width. I made 4 buttons:
(example: http://orasvirtual.ro/images/b.JPG)
increase height, decrease height, increase width and decrease width. 
I've made this until now, but how to make to increase/decrease holding the click for x seconds.

thanks for all

ok, until now I've made this, thanks to NullPointer:

html:

```
<div  id='divid'>div</div>
<button id="inch" >+ h</button>
<button id="dech" >- h</button>
<button id="incw" >+ w</button>
<button id="decw" >- w</button>
```

jquery:

```
$("#inch").click(function(){

var height = $("#divid").height()+1; //to decrease just -1 instead of 1

$("#divid").height( height );
})
$("#dech").click(function(){

var height = $("#divid").height()-1; //to decrease just -1 instead of 1

$("#divid").height( height );
})
$("#incw").click(function(){

var width= $("#divid").width()+1; //to decrease just -1 instead of 1

$("#divid").width( width );
})
$("#decw").click(function(){

var width= $("#divid").width()-1; //to decrease just -1 instead of 1

$("#divid").width( width );
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9b52T/4/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the width/height of the `window` object, but you can change the width and height of the `body` element.

```
$('#increaseWidth').click(function(){
    $('body').width(function(i, w){
       return w + 1
    })
})

$('#decreaseHeight').click(function(){
    $('body').height(function(i, h){
       return h - 1
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HsHj8/

Answer (score 0):

If the window element is `$(window)` use the below code

Increase Width:

```
$(window).width($(window).width() + 1 + "px")
```

Decrease Width:

```
$(window).width($(window).width() - 1 + "px")
```

Increase Height:

```
$(window).height($(window).height() + 1 + "px")
```

Decrease Height:

```
$(window).height($(window).height() - 1 + "px")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that in most of the situations.

**From sources:**

Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a window in a browser, according to the following rules:

1. You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
2. You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

For some supported browsers you can use following to resize your browser window.

```
window.resizeTo(w,h);
```